# Show route only after promise is resolved - Error

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to show route only after promise is resolved. In controller I am getting my data. But keep getting below error and further processing stops. Not sure what I missed.

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: loadOrderDataProvider <- loadOrderData

Here is what I am doing. I am configuring route via methods in the $routeProvider object.

```
    .when('/customers/openOrder', {
    templateUrl: 'views/customers/Order.html',
    controller: "orderController",
    resolve: {
    loadOrderData: function(loadOrderService){
    return loadOrderService.loadOrderData();
    },
}
})

Following is a simple implementation of the methods exposed by the loadOrderService    service and followed by controller code that consume loadOrderData from routeProvider.

    angular.module("app.orderModule", ["app.anotherOrderModule"])
.factory("loadOrderService", function($http){
return {

    loadOrderData : function () {

var promise = $http({ 
    method: 'GET', 
    url: 'getOrderData()' })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    return data;
});
return promise;
}
};
})      
.controller("orderController", [ '$scope', '$http', 'loadOrderData'
    function ( $scope, $http, loadOrderData) {
    alert('Loaded in controller ' + loadOrderData.data[0].orderName); // **** I AM GETTING orderName HERE


}
]);
```

Comment: Please provide more context and/or a [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/). Also provide the app/app configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately, plunker is restricted in my network.

Comment: But, issue is with loadOrderData in resolves is not getting injected in controller

Comment: Though loadOrderData is not getting injected in controller, but i am able to print the data using alert();

Answer (score 0):

You have a bogus comma after in your resolve obj

```
resolve: {
    loadOrderData: function(loadOrderService){
    return loadOrderService.loadOrderData();
    },//???
}
```

Comment: Removing bogus comma did not help.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is with this snippet of code since this error is usually caused by a syntax error in the declaration of your modules or services.